# Using find, how to classify like ls -F ? (directories with a trailing slash)

Tags: bash, grep, find

I use `find` to get a list of files, then I grep it to do a path matching :

```
$ find pc* | grep -i arthur
pc6/arthurv/untitled-2.py
pc6/arthurv/untitled-3.py
pc6/arthur.py
pc9/Arthur 4C
pc9/Arthur 4C/untitled-1.py
pc9/Arthur 4C/untitled-2.py
```

I would like to do like in `ls -F` and append a `/` for each directory.

Alternatively, how do I get find to show all directories matching case insensitive `arthur` ?

Comment: Related: [How to use wc and piping to find how many files and directories are in a certain directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/101442)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use disjunctions in `find` expressions to implement conditional processing; with GNU `find`:

```
find pc* -type d -printf "%p/\n" -o -print
```

will find everything in paths starting with the files and directories matching “pc*”, and print their names, followed by a “/” if they’re directories.

The way this works is as follows:

- `pc*` specifies the paths to start from;
- `-type d` matches directories;
- `-printf "%p/\n"` prints the path to the currently-processed file, followed by “/” and a newline; because it follows `-type d`, it is only executed if `-type d` matched (there’s an implicit conjunction);
- `-o` introduces a disjunction: the expression following it will be evaluated if the expression preceding it did not match (and the expression preceding it is `-type d -printf "%p/\n"` here, because conjunctions have higher precedence than disjunctions);
- `-print` prints the path to the currently-processed file.

Showing all directories matching case-insensitive “arthur” can be done using other `find` expressions:

```
find . -type d -iname "*arthur*"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, however I understand easily the second code and the third but not the first one, I would put it last and explain more in details.

Comment: You removerd the version `find pc* \( -type d -printf "%p/\n" \) -o \( ! -type d -print \)`, just curious about what the parenthesis and the `!` meant ? :)

Comment: The parentheses group expressions, and `!` negates an expression. So `\( -type d -printf "%p/\n" \) -o \( ! -type d -print \)` tells `find` to consider `-type d -printf "%p/\n"` on the one hand, and `! -type d -print` on the other; and `! -type d` matches anything which isn’t a directory.

Answer (score 3):

`find` has a huge amount of options and details. Another variant is to use `-printf` with `%y`

```
$ find . -printf "%p:%y\n"
./dir:d
./file:f
```

where `%y` adds a "d" or a "f" just like `ls -l`

```
$ find . -printf "%p%y\n" | sed 's!d$!/! ; s!f$!!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto the answers here to list all files and directories:

```bsh
cat <(find old.files -type d -printf "%p/\n") <(find old.files -type f)
```

output:

```
dir1/dir2/
dir1/test.txt
dir1/dir2/test2.txt
```

Where previously the issue `dir1/dir2` not having a trailing slash:

```
dir1/dir2
dir1/test.txt
dir1/dir2/test2.txt
```

Ultimately for being able to compare a tar file and directory.

```
diff <(tar tf old.files.tar | sort -u) <(cat <(find old.files -type d -printf "%p/\n") <(find old.files -type f) | sort -u)
```